# Question about the product topology

Tags: general-topology

Theorem 7.8 Suppose $(X_n,\mathcal T_n ), n \in \Bbb N,$ is a sequence of topological spaces.

Let $\mathcal B'$  consist of all subsets of $\Pi_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n$ which are of the form $$U_1 \times \cdots \times U_N \times X_{N+1} \times \cdots= \{(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}| x_n \in U_n, 1\leq n \leq N \} $$
Where $N\geq 1 $ and $U_n $ is in $ \mathcal T_n $ for all $ 1\leq n \leq N $.

The collection $\mathcal B' $ is a basis for a topology on $\Pi_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n$ called the product topolgy.

I am studying for an exam and would like to know how to prove the above theorem; though my prof says we need not know the proofs of theorems for our exam i think learning the proof of this would be a meaningful learning experience and would like to know how to prove this and our textbook does not do so. A reference to where this is proved our proof would be much appreciated.

Edit: do i just need to prove that $\mathcal B'$ is a basis? or do i need something more than that?

Comment: Is your question "what is to be proved"? Then you've already answered it: you need to show that $\mathcal{B}'$ is a basis.

Comment: Well i would like a proof or reference to one, but if i know what i need to prove at least i can try it myself. it just feels a bit weird what it states shouldn't it be a definition?

Comment: The covering property should be easy to see. For the intersection property, write down two general elements $B_1$ and $B_2$ of $\mathcal{B}'$ and some $x$ in their intersection and check where you can find $B_3 \in \mathcal{B}'$  such that $x\in B_3 \subseteq B_1\cap B_2$.

Comment: hmm, whats something in there intersection look like? it looks like an infinite sequence sort of like a point in each ball? or is it somehow diffrent?

Comment: Let $B_1 = U_1 \times \ldots \times U_{N_1} \times X_{N_1+1} \times \ldots$ and similarly $B_2 = V_1 \times \ldots \times V_{N_2} \times X_{N_2+1} \times \ldots$ and then try from there...

Comment: oh each $U_i$ is in the topology it need not be a point!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73106/discussion-between-theindigamer-and-faust).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the statement of the theorem is that that family forms a basis for the topology, then yes, to prove the theorem all you need is to show it forms a basis.

It is clear that $\mathcal B'$ covers $X = \prod_{n \in \mathbb N}X_n$: actually $X \in \mathcal B'$ (just take $U_n = X_n$, for all $n$).

Now let $U, V \in \mathcal B'$.
Then there exist $m,n \in \mathbb N$, and $U_i, V_i \in \mathcal T_i$ such that
$$U = U_1 \times \cdots \times U_n \times X_{n+1} \times X_{n+2} \times \cdots$$
and
$$V = V_1 \times \cdots \times V_m \times X_{m+1} \times X_{m+2} \times \cdots.$$
Suppose, wlog, $n \leq m$ and then define $U_{n+1} = X_{n+1}, \ldots,  U_m = X_m$.
Then $W_i = U_i \cap V_i \in \mathcal T_i$ and $U \cap V = W$.

This is enough to prove that $\mathcal B'$ is a [basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)) for a topology on $X$ (notice the statement by the end of the second paragraph after definition: "A sufficient but not necessary condition for..."), and it is indeed the [product topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology).